# Weighted mean of an object (Centers of mass)

Tags: geometry, arithmetic

I am having trouble understanding the concept. Usually when I calculate the center of mass of an object when given area and dimensions I'd multiply corresponding distances with areas etc then divide-by the total are (Given that we're using a 2D shape).

However when I come to this question for example:
[image]

I worked out the following: $(3*6^{2})-({\pi*3^{2}\over 2})(6-{4\over \pi})$ which is meant to give the center of mass, but I was under the assumption you must divide by the total area as per usual?

May someone explain to me why this isn't the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell how you're calculating it, but I find the CoM $y$-coord, $y_M$, as follows. Firstly, the area is easily calculated (without calculus):

\begin{eqnarray*}
A &=& 6^2 - \dfrac{\pi \cdot 3^2}{2} = 36 - \dfrac{9\pi}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, assuming vertex $A$ is at $(-3,0)$ in the Cartesian plane,

\begin{eqnarray*}
y_M &=& \dfrac{1}{A} \int_{-3}^{3} \dfrac{1}{2}(f(x)^2 - g(x)^2)\;dx \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{2A} \int_{-3}^{3} (6^2 - (9-x^2))\;dx \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{2A} \int_{-3}^{3} (x^2 +27)\;dx \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{2A} \bigg[\dfrac{x^3}{3} + 27x \bigg]_{-3}^{3} \\
&=& \dfrac{9+81}{A} \\
&=& \dfrac{20}{8-\pi} \\ 
&& \\
\therefore\quad \text{Distance to CoM from $CD$ is } && 6 - \dfrac{20}{8-\pi}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks a lot! Makes more sense!